# Debug Error! HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED in C

Tags: c

I tried to use dynamic allocation and I didnt sucsses to write it without warnings. I get debbug error with the 'free' function:

[image: the warning message]

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define size 1

int* symetri(int set1[size], int set2[size]);

int main() {
    int* difference;
    int set1[size], set2[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &set1[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &set2[i]);
    difference = symetri(set1, set2);
    free(difference);
    return 0;
}

int* symetri(int set1[size], int set2[size])
{
    int* new_arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    while (new_arr == NULL)
        new_arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int counter = 0;
    bool sym;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new_arr[counter] = set1[i];
        counter++;
    }
    new_arr[counter] = -1;
    return new_arr;
}
```

Comment: The last `new_arr[counter] = -1` writes one element past the end of the allocate `new_arr`.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.

Comment: You assign `new_array[counter] = -1` after the loop. Then `counter = size`, i.e. you access `new_arr[1]` but there is only size for one integer.

Comment: You don't have enough space for the last assignment (`new_arr[counter] = -1;`): `new_arr[counter]` does not exist

Comment: And, incidentally, if the first call of `malloc()` returns `NULL`, the odds are good that the second call (which immediately attempts to allocate exactly the same amount of memory) will also return `NULL`.    But you're not checking if the second call succeeds before using the allocated memory as an array.

Comment: thanks! now its working

Comment: In future these sorts of errors can be debugged with valgrind, and address sanitizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `free` crashes with an error message about heap corruption in a program this simple, it's almost certainly because you wrote to memory that doesn't belong to you. And you did, with this line at the end of `symetri`:

```
new_arr[counter] = -1;
```

You need to make your allocation of `new_arr` another `sizeof(int)` longer if you want to write to the end after looping over it.